# Find the mistake (AM GM ineqality)

Tags: means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

According to AM GM inequality

$$\frac{\left(x^3-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x}\right)}{4}\ge\left[(x^3)\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\Rightarrow x^3 \ge 2^\frac{9}{4}\;\;\;\;;\; 
\forall\; x\in \mathbb R^+ $$
which is not true

Comment: AMGM only works on positive values. Here, two of your brackets on the RHS are clearly negative

Comment: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the AM-GM is equivalent to saying something like $$\frac{2 + (-1) + (-1)}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{2(-1)(-1)}.$$  It doesn't work because we require each term to be a nonnegative real number.

Answer (score 0):

The $GM-AM$ said the following

Let $$a,b>0 \, \, \text{Then the following inequality holds} \sqrt{ab}< \frac{a+b}{2}$$

as @Benjamin Wang remark your RHS is non positive.